# Mixed Tsirelson Norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, ramsey-theory

A couple of days ago I posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722894/mixed-tsirelson-norm) question on Mathematics Stack Exchange. Surprisingly, so far, I haven't received any answers or comments about it (besides my own possible answer). Maybe I can get more feedback over here.

Comment: Here is some feedback: wait a few days more, and then post the question details instead of the link.  If you think you have the answer, then the question should not be "Am I right?" but instead "Is step X correct?", where step X is specific and indeed something on which you have some doubt.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Asking Properly" Paseman, 2014.03.26

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. If k is the cardinality of the support of x then the final norm of x is equal to the k norm. In most cases you can do better. In Tsirelson space you can stop at approximately the (k-1)/2 norm. This is pretty easy to prove. You can find a discussion at the end of Casazza and Schura's book.